# CSS: 100% page height, no scrolling, working in IE7

Tags: css, internet-explorer, scroll, height

Preface:
I have read probably 3 dozen answers on here about 100% height CSS in IE7, but none seem to answer my extremely simple question.  If this is a duplicate, I apologize, but I cannot find the existing answer.

Question:
I have a simple website with a navigation bar on the left side.  On some pages the content of the page requires scrolling down, on other pages it does not.

I want to make it so that the navigation background extends all the way to the bottom of the page, regardless of whether scrolling is required or not, but I do not want to introduce scrolling if the content does not already require it.

So far I've found the following:

```
position: absolute;
height: 100%;
```

Results in adding scrolling if it's not already there AND if the content naturally requires scrolling the background will stop early.

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

Works exactly right on Firefox and Chrome, but not IE7+

I figured a work-around of repeating a background image on the HTML element of the color, but that means if I want to change the color I have to generate a new image, which seems silly.

Answer (score 1):

IE7 supports position:fixed if some doctype is specified.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head><title>title</title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body{ height:100%; margin:0; padding:0; }
.nav{ position:fixed; left:0; top:0; height:100%; background-color:#ccc; width:100px; }
.very-high{ height:3000px; margin-left:110px; }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="nav">div class="nav"</div>
    <div class="very-high">a div with height:3000px</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Created a [demo on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdVGL/)